# Why v-model is not updating in text

Tags: vue.js

```html
<template>
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                Numbers Checked
            </div>
            <div class="card-body card-info color-accent" v-model="numbers_checked" v-text="numbers_checked">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props:
        [
          'overviewAnalytics',
        ],

    data() {
      return {
        numbers_checked: this.overviewAnalytics.numbers_checked
      };
    },
    created() {
      this.channelTemperatureReading.listen('TemperatureReadingUpdate', reading => {
        axios.get('/home/get-overview-analytics').then(resp => {
          this.numbers_checked = 12; //resp.data.numbers_checked + 100;
        });
      });
    },
    computed: {
      channelTemperatureReading() {
        return window.Echo.channel('temperature-reading');
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

I've tried everything but text is not updating. Confirmed from every aspect that data does change.

Changes from AXIOS are coming just ok. I even tried to put custom value but no avail.

I don't what is issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be misusing *computed* properties which [rely on reactive dependencies to execute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) however yours is wrapping `window.Echo.channel('temperature-reading')` which Vue knows nothing about.

I suggest you remove the `computed` property and use something like this

```js
created() {
  const channel = window.Echo.channel('temperature-reading')
  channel.listen('TemperatureReadingUpdate', reading => {
    axios.get('/home/get-overview-analytics').then(({ data }) => {
      // console.log('get-overview-analytics', data.numbers_checked)
      this.numbers_checked = data.numbers_checked + 100
    })
  })
}
```

As others have mentioned, `v-model` is not appropriate here so you should also remove that.

Comment: data() {
      return {
        numbers_checked: this.overviewAnalytics.numbers_checked
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.numbers_checked = 12;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.numbers_checked = 14;
        console.log(this.numbers_checked);
      }, 4000);
    }

 <div class="card-header">
                Numbers Checked
            </div>

console log says 14 but not the vue element

Comment: @AliRaza are you saying it stays at `12` in the page? I find that reasonably difficult to believe. Do you think you could reproduce it in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @AliRaza I tried to reproduce your simple example above and it works as expected ~ https://jsfiddle.net/u8ek90fx/

Comment: Yes I did check it works there, but not in my code, just bear with me, Trying to find out what's wrong exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` only works on `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements

Comment: All I want is to update the text when I change the data.

Comment: Great help. I was confused why it is not working with Ionic framework where <ion-input v-model=""></ion-input>
I need to change all of them as <input/> again..!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `v-model` with `div`, it's for inputs.

```
<div v-text="numbers_checked"></div>
```

From the documentation on `v-model`:

> Usage: Create a two-way binding on a form input element or a
>   component.

Comment: <div class="card-body card-info color-accent">
                {{numbers_checked}}
   </div>

But updated value is not reflecting.